# Transform Optional String and return Date in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, option-type

I am currently parsing a nullable String to a Date. I try to use Optional to avoid using if statement. Here is what I have written so far :

```
Client client = new Client();

Optional.ofNullable(methodThatMayReturnStringOrNull())
.ifPresent((s) -> {
    try {
    client.setBirthDate(DateUtils.parseDate(
        StringUtils.substring(s, 0, 10),
        new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd"}));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new TechnicalException("error.parsing.date", e);
    }
});
```

Is it possible to transform this lambda so I can make it a method similar to the following but java 8 style?

```
private Date parse(String complexString) {
    Date birthDate = null;
    if (complexString != null) {
        try {
            birthDate = DateUtils.parseDate(
                    StringUtils.substring(complexString, 0, 10),
                    new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd"});
        } catch (final ParseException e) {
            throw new TechnicalException("error.parsing.date", e);
        }
    }
    return birthDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how far you want to go, but you can start with

```
Optional<Date> date = Optional.ofNullable(methodThatMayReturnStringOrNull())
.map((s) -> {
    try {
    return DateUtils.parseDate(
        StringUtils.substring(s, 0, 10),
        new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd"}));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new TechnicalException("error.parsing.date", e);
    }
});
```

You might also consider using `flatMap` instead of `map` and returning empty optional instead of throwing exception on error - depends on how you want to progress you flow.

On completely unrelated note, get rid of Date and use either joda or new java time classes ;)